# Handle error when server does not respond

Tags: javascript, angular

My application is build using Angular 2. A typical pattern I use is seen below. If there is a server error I do a number of things depending on the needs. In the below example I used a comment to indicate a redirect to an error page.

However occasionally something goes wrong and the server does not respond causing the front end to remain in a state of pending with the spinner spinning. I want to know how this kind of situation is dealt with. Is there a common practice for this? Is there a way to redirect at some point in a elegant manner? I feel like I could add a timeout to trigger at a certain time but that really seems like a hack.

```
private getSites() {
  this.spinner.show();
  this.sitesService.getSites(1)
    .subscribe(
      _data => {
        this.sites = _data;
        this.spinner.hide();
        this.loading = false;
      },
      _error => {
        // Redirect to < something went wrong >
        this.spinner.hide();
      }
    );

}
```

Comment: So `spinner.hide()` doesn't get called? Why does your spinner keeps spinning on error?

Comment: Using timeouts is fairly common with network communication that is prone to failure.  The angular $http object has support for timeouts in its config.timeout property.  It's not a hack!

Comment: Basically, your code is correct and everything should work fine. Just make sure that `spinner.hide` really gets called (do `console.log('qqq')` from inside of `hide` method). If that works, it might be standard issue with `changeDetection` mechanism... I would say it is broken in Angular4, but developers don't admit it as for now. Try to add to Spinner class `contructor(private ref ChangeDetectorRef){}` and `this.ref.detectChanges()` to `hide` method.

Comment: I appreciate the response. Thank you.

Comment: @sabithpocker . The code works fine. I was just using it as an example. The only time the spinner keeps going is when something happens and there is not server response, so the app basically hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the responses I was able to learn various ways to deal with this situation. The one I liked best was using timeout operator. Thanks everyone.

```
private getSites() {
  this.spinner.show();
  this.sitesService.getSites(1)
    .timeout(6000)
    .subscribe(
      _data => {
        this.sites = _data;
        this.spinner.hide();
        this.loading = false;
      },
      _error => {
        // Redirect to < something went wrong >
        this.spinner.hide();
      }
    );

}
```